# SmartRefresher's multiple refresh controllers error in TabContainer

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh

### Flutter TabContainer with SmartRefresher Error

I'm trying to use a `TabContainer` from the `tab_container` package in Flutter, along with `SmartRefresher` on each tab. However, I'm encountering an error that says, `Don't use one refreshController to multiple SmartRefresher, it will cause some unexpected bugs mostly in TabBarView.` This happens when I'm using separate `RefreshController` instances for each tab.

#### What I Want to Achieve

I want to have a `TabContainer` with two tabs, each containing a `SmartRefresher` for pull-to-refresh functionality.

#### Error Description

The error occurs when I switch between tabs, indicating that the `RefreshController` is being reused across the tabs, which results in this issue.

#### Code

```dart
class AlarmsList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Alarm> alarms;
  final List<TriggeredAlarm> triggeredAlarms;
  final Future Function()? onRefresh;
  final Function(int) onDeleteAlarm;
  final Function(int) onDeleteTriggeredAlarm;
  
  // ...

  RefreshController untriggeredRefreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);
  RefreshController triggeredRefreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
      child: TabContainer(
        color: Colors.white,
        tabEdge: TabEdge.top,
        controller: tabController,
        // ... tab styles and configuration ...

        children: [
          _buildUntriggeredAlarmsList(context),
          _buildTriggeredAlarmsList(context),
        ],
        tabs: [
          // ... tab labels ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildUntriggeredAlarmsList(BuildContext context) {
    untriggeredRefreshController = RefreshController();
    return SmartRefresher(
      key: Key('untriggered'),
      enablePullDown: true,
      enablePullUp: false,
      controller: untriggeredRefreshController,
      onRefresh: () async {
        // ... refresh logic ...
      },
      // ... content ...
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTriggeredAlarmsList(BuildContext context) {
    triggeredRefreshController = RefreshController();
    return SmartRefresher(
      key: Key('triggered'),
      enablePullDown: true,
      enablePullUp: false,
      controller: triggeredRefreshController,
      onRefresh: () async {
        // ... refresh logic ...
      },
      // ... content ...
    );
  }

  // ... other functions ...
}
```

#### What I tried to do

1. Using `final` `RefreshController`

I initially created two `final RefreshController` instances within the class, one for "Untriggered Alarms" and one for "Triggered Alarms." I assigned these controllers to their respective `SmartRefresher` widgets.

2. Creating RefreshController in build Function

I also tried creating non-final RefreshController instances directly within the build function.

3. Giving Unique Keys

To ensure that each SmartRefresher is treated as a distinct widget, I assigned unique keys to them. I used Key('untriggered') and Key('triggered') to differentiate between the two.

4. Initializing RefreshController Directly

As a further troubleshooting step, I tried initializing the RefreshController objects directly within the SmartRefresher widgets.

```
SmartRefresher(
  controller: RefreshController(), // Tried this
  // ...
)
```

5. Removing Transition Builder

As a further troubleshooting step, I attempted to remove the transition builder from the TabContainer. My hope was that it might have been causing conflicts with the SmartRefresher. However, even after this removal, the error remained.

Comment: I've created my own implementation of a mechanism similar to the `TabContainer`, but instead, I decided to use `AnimationSwitcher`.

Interestingly, when I used a basic fade transition with the `AnimationSwitcher`, there were no errors at all. However, the error occured when I added the transition builder with a slide transition effect.